# How to get the wrapped instance of a i18n component while testing

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have a simple form component that looks a bit like:

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';

class MyForm extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {testString: this.props.testString};
}

render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (<p>
                <span>{t('test')}</span>
                <em>{this.state.testString}</em>
            </p>);
}

}

export default translate()(MyForm);
```

And I want to test changes on the "state" using jest like this:

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { I18nextProvider, translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import MyForm from './MyForm';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import i18n from 'i18next';

i18n.init({react: {withRef: true}});

it('Test my form', async () => {
const item = await mount(<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}><MyForm/></I18nextProvider>);
item.getWrappedInstance().setState({testString: 'test'});
});
```

I would like to have access to the wrapped instance to change some states. My problem is that somehow i18n doesn't load the ref, and I always get the error:

```
TypeError: item.getWrappedInstance is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using refs in the wrapped component like this:

```js
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { I18nextProvider, translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import MyForm from './MyForm';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import i18n from 'i18next';

i18n.init({react: {withRef: true}});

it('Test my form', async () => {
    let instance;
    const item = await mount(<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}><MyForm ref={(element) => { instance = element; }}/></I18nextProvider>);
    instance.getWrappedInstance().setState({testString: 'test'});
    console.log(item.find('em').node.outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: there is a complete chapter about testing here: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing.html